# FieldInfo.GetValue() returns null for a nested static class public static fields

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, c#-8.0, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to get filed values in a nested static class by this simple code:

```
public static class DataConstants {

    public static class Roles {

        public static readonly Role[] All = new Lazy<Role[]>(LoadAllRoles).Value;

        private static Role[] LoadAllRoles() {
            var fields = typeof(DataConstants.Roles)
                         .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            foreach (var field in fields) {
                var r = field.GetValue(null);
            }
            return blah-blah;
        }

        public static readonly Role Role1 = new Role {
            Id        = -1,
            Name      = "role1",
        };

        public static Role Role2 = new Role {
            Id        = -2,
            Name      = "role2",
        };

    }

}
```

Everything seems to be fine and I think this should work. But calling the `field.GetValue(null)` always returns `null`. Have you any idea what I missed here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of static initialisation. Static members are initialised in the order that they're declared, and `All` is declared before `Role1` or `Role2`. So `Role1` and `Role2` aren't assigned until after `All` is assigned.

Note that your use of `Lazy<T>` here is pointless: you're immediately calling `.Value`, which means that `LoadAllRoles` is called during the initialisation of `All`. If `All` was actually a `Lazy<T>` (or was a property which wrapped a `Lazy<T>`), and `Lazy<T>.Value` was *only* called after `Role1` and `Role2` were initialised, you wouldn't see this issue.

You can move the declarations of `Role1` and `Role2` to the top of the type, above `All`, which "fixes" the issue. You'd be better off assigning `All` inside a static constructor though, as this is less prone to accidental breakage:

```
public static class DataConstants {

    public static class Roles {
        public static readonly Role[] All;

        static Roles()
        {
            All = LoadAllRoles();   
        }

        private static Role[] LoadAllRoles() {
            var fields = typeof(DataConstants.Roles)
                         .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            foreach (var field in fields) {
                var r = field.GetValue(null);
                Console.WriteLine("field: " + r);
            }

            return new Role[0];
        }

        public static readonly Role Role1 = new Role {
            Id        = -1,
            Name      = "role1",
        };

        public static Role Role2 = new Role {
            Id        = -2,
            Name      = "role2",
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, it's the fact that they're creating a `Lazy` and immediately calling `Value` on it that raises the issue, right? If they actually used the laziness, they should be okay?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's worth making a note of: I've edited my answer

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, if they change it to return `Lazy` instead then get the value it works.

Comment: @canton7 May I use a f-word here? Holy [] []. Why I missed that? Thanks a lot.